# Uploading .apk on Oculus AppLab. Error: app contains both 32-bit and 64-bit libraries and your application contains android.permission.CAMERA

Tags: unity-game-engine, apk, oculus, app-lab

Whenever I try to upload a new version of .apk file on Oculus App Lab, I get this message:

Error: The upload could not be completed because your application contains the following Android permissions that are not supported: - android.permission.CAMERA Please remove the following permissions and upload your application binary again.

Warning:
This app contains both 32-bit (armeabi-v7a) and 64-bit (arm64-v8a) libraries. This consumes extra storage and increases download times. Consider updating your build to target 64-bit only.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WauJN.png)

In my player settings under Android, I have selected only 64-bit library and unselected 32-bit library. However the problem still persist and I have no idea how I could remove ndroid.permission.CAMERA ?

Comment: What you configure in Android emulator is totally irrelevant. oculus wants to to configure the build process aof the app so that the APK only contains arm64 libraries. Use `abiFilter`  and configure it to `arm64-v8a`.